# How can I set grafana 7 to work with warp10 2.7.x?

Tags: grafana, warp10

I've just install a fresh warp10 standalone server version 2.7.2.
Using beamium to send data into it and seeing the data via the VScode plugin is OK and I can see graph in GTS preview.

I've also installed a fresh grafana and warp10-plugin following the warp10 recommandation on the ovh github.

When execution a default warp10 query (via editor), grafana add some strings in the query, like the `start` or `end` value, so in the end the query look like:

```
1609947849757000 'start' STORE
'2021-01-06T15:44:09.757Z' 'startISO' STORE 
1610034249757000 'end' STORE 
'2021-01-07T15:44:09.757Z' 'endISO' STORE 
86400000000 'interval' STORE 
199538106 '__interval' STORE 
199538 '__interval_ms' STORE 
[ 'host.local.domain' ] 'host_list' STORE
```

But when executing, there is an error poping in the warp10 logs, after decryption it tell:

```
Exception at '=>1609947849757000<= 'start' STORE '2021-01-06T15:44:09.757Z'' in section [TOP]
```

It seems that it don't take the LONG (DOUBLE?) number for what it is, and try to match a function with the same name that don't exists.

On grafana side, I don't have any valuable help, it tell me:

```
WarpScript Failure on Line -1, Unable to read x-warp10-error-line and x-warp10-error-line headers in server answer
```

Do I miss something ?

==== Edit: 2021-01-07 17:32 UTC

After first reply, doing other test:

I've tryied the same query, and the error is still the same.

[Warpscript failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tFnM.png)

But in VScode this query works:

```
{
  'token' $RTOKEN
  'class' '~.*'
  'labels' {}
  'end' '2021-01-07T17:35:28.086Z'
  'timespan' 21600000000
} FETCH
```

I've also try to use the `bartender` stuff in grafana and it work fine too...

So everything should work, I must miss the obvious.
Can Java version have an impact ?

Comment: I've re-installed Java to the last 1.8 version, warp10 to 2.7.2, restart all, and it's working now.. the only annoying things is that grafana don't see the x-warp10-error-message I've to go check the header, but it's OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the datasource is working, you didn't miss anything.
Do you use the built in warpscript editor ? Make sure you ticked the "WarpScript Editor" checkbox:
[image: screnshot grafana simple request]

Then, do the simplest FETCH request you can do, or copy paste the code you did in VSCode.

You can define your own variables too in the datasource configuration. It is usefull for tokens.

I just setup Grafana 7.3.6 + ovh plugin to check, it seems there is no regression issue.

The full WarpScript can be found in the browser console.

The header error is linked to Grafana 7, no problem with Grafana 6.x. Install Grafana 6.x if you want WarpSript detailed errors.

*Edit: Issue is now fixed and merged into [ovh github](https://github.com/ovh/ovh-warp10-datasource/issues/81) master.*

If you want to test another Warp 10 data source, you can use the credential and advices in [this article](https://blog.senx.io/grafana-beertender-dashboard/). You just need to go before covid lockdown to find relevant office beertender data...